# How to find which side of the div is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I need to know side of the div is clicked. How to find that. When i hover the border of the div the mouse will change to col-resize.

But I cant find at which side of the div the  mouse is currenty..

Please help..

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? Show html? And make a fiddle?

Comment: Do you mean how to get coordinates of mouse currently in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to play with this:

```
$("#something").click(function(e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
});
```